# Cannot start VPN using Toyvpn

Tags: android, sockets, network-programming, vpn, datagram

I'll try to be as descriptive as possible 
I'm new to android and i'm making an android application 
In that application i'd like to be able to see the address of the HTTP requests going OUT from the mobile (On what website they are heading).
So i've looked around and i found out that to do that , I need to use a VPN and android 4.0+ has a VPNService supplied from google implemented using ToyVPNService
So i got this service and started changing in it so i can use it without the need of using a server 
I'd like to work the VPN as follows:
1-Capture the HTTP requests 
2-Read their destination
3-Resend them back to their way

So i took the VPNService and i started modifying it so that i don't need an actual server 
Here's the code i'm using

```
    package com.example.testingservice;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.VpnService;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel;
import java.util.Enumeration;
public class SO1 extends VpnService implements Handler.Callback, Runnable {
private static final String TAG = "ToyVpnService";

private Handler mHandler;
private Thread mThread;

private ParcelFileDescriptor mInterface;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // The handler is only used to show messages.
    if (mHandler == null) {
        mHandler = new Handler(this);
    }

    // Stop the previous session by interrupting the thread.
    if (mThread != null) {
        mThread.interrupt();
    }

    // Start a new session by creating a new thread.
    mThread = new Thread(this, "ToyVpnThread");
    mThread.start();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mThread != null) {
        mThread.interrupt();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
    if (message != null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message.what, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public synchronized void run() {
    Log.i(TAG,"running vpnService");
    try {
        runVpnConnection();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        //Log.e(TAG, "Got " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        try {
            mInterface.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }
        mInterface = null;

        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(R.string.disconnected);
        Log.i(TAG, "Exiting");
    }
}

private boolean runVpnConnection() throws Exception {

    configure();

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(mInterface.getFileDescriptor());

    // Allocate the buffer for a single packet.
    ByteBuffer packet = ByteBuffer.allocate(32767);

    // We keep forwarding packets till something goes wrong.
    while (true) {
        // Assume that we did not make any progress in this iteration.
        boolean idle = true;

        // Read the outgoing packet from the input stream.
        int length = in.read(packet.array());
        if (length > 0) {

            Log.i(TAG,"************new packet");
            System.exit(-1);
            while (packet.hasRemaining()) {
                Log.i(TAG,""+packet.get());
                //System.out.print((char) packet.get());
            }
            packet.limit(length);
            //  tunnel.write(packet);
            packet.clear();

            // There might be more outgoing packets.
            idle = false;
        }
        Thread.sleep(50);
    }
}

public String getLocalIpAddress()
{
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                Log.i(TAG,"****** INET ADDRESS ******");
                Log.i(TAG,"address: "+inetAddress.getHostAddress());
                Log.i(TAG,"hostname: "+inetAddress.getHostName());
                Log.i(TAG,"address.toString(): "+inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString());
                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    //IPAddresses.setText(inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString());
                    Log.i(TAG,"IS NOT LOOPBACK ADDRESS: "+inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString());
                    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                } else{
                    Log.i(TAG,"It is a loopback address");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        String LOG_TAG = null;
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.toString());
    }

    return null;
}

private void configure() throws Exception {
    // If the old interface has exactly the same parameters, use it!
    if (mInterface != null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Using the previous interface");
        return;
    }

    // Configure a builder while parsing the parameters.
    Builder builder = new Builder();
    String SS=getLocalIpAddress();
    builder.setMtu(1500);
  //  builder.addAddress("10.0.0.2", 24);
    builder.addAddress(SS, 24);
   // builder.addAddress(SS,24);
    builder.addRoute("0.0.0.0",0);
    try {
        mInterface.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore
    }

    mInterface = builder.establish();
}}
```

The problem is this line

```
mInterface = builder.setSession("GITVPN").setConfigureIntent(mConfigureIntent).establish();
```

the Establish returns NULL and i can't seem to get it working 
I'm thinking there is a problem with the addresses
I'd like to work it that there's no server , and there would be a tunnel that reads the packets 
I've seen some other post that said i should make the addresses to 10.0.0.2 instead of external ips ( 192.168.x.x) and i should add route (0.0.0.0,0) 
However the descriptor file keeps returning null and i can't seem to fix it 
Any help will be appreciated , and sorry if this sounded that it was repeated but i'm super stuck and you guys are my only hope

Answer (score 1):

You can't run the VpnService and establish a VPN connection without having a server that you communicate with and forwards the traffic to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Check the IP address you assigned to the interface, it should not be the same as other adapters.
What the builder operated on is a TUN device, which is created for VPN service.
So, IP address of the TUN should be proper set.
Make the address conflict with others is not a good idea.

Also, Step 3 you mentioned is not quite easy as Android not support raw socket.

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I've already given up hope on this matter , No matter what i do it will not work

Answer (score 0):

just to revive an old thread...

- `VpnService` requires a users interaction to start and won't work without it
- the `ToyVpnClient` puts a button on the screen that the user has to click and once that's done, the Builder method will return the interface

so, steps to make it work are;
1. build a button on your app
2. `onclick` of that button, call `VpnService.prepare(this);`  (this = your app context)
3. `Builder.establish()` will now return a VPN interface